# What happens when BEFORE DELETE ON "table" trigger fails in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, innodb, rollback

My question is a general question about *before triggers*.

What happens when a BEFORE DELETE ON "table" fails for some reason (say a foreign key constraint when trying to delete a row.)?

If before it fails, it updates a few fields in another table. Are these changes effective even if the affected rows are not deleted?

Comment: The transaction is rolled back and no changes occur.

Comment: Thank you very much @GordonLinoff, is this true for all MYSQL storage engines?

Comment: @Goodol'George it is true for only those storage engines which support transactions. eg: It will work for InnoDB, but not MyISAM

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the transaction is not rolled back. The DELETE is canceled, but if one were using non-autocommit transactions, there might be other SQL statements before or after the DELETE that can still be committed.

Comment: Do you check for errors and do a `ROLLBACK`?

Answer (score 1):

It is there in the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> - If a BEFORE trigger fails, the operation on the corresponding row is
>     not performed.
> - An error during either a BEFORE or AFTER trigger results in failure of the entire statement that caused trigger invocation.
> - For transactional tables, failure of a statement should cause rollback of all changes performed by the statement. Failure of a trigger causes the statement to fail, so trigger failure also causes rollback. For nontransactional tables, such rollback cannot be done, so although the statement fails, any changes performed prior to the point of the error remain in effect.

Comment: Great just what I was looking for^^